# Using flexbox to align one element to the top left and one to the center on a page

Tags: css, flexbox

When I try to put one element in the top left and one in the center, the top element doesn't go all the way to the left. How do I accomplish this?

```css
.Aligner {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.Aligner-item {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.Aligner-item--top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="Aligner">
    <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--top">…</div>
    <div class="Aligner-item">…</div>
    <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--bottom">…</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVjzzo

Comment: How are you expecting this to look?

Comment: Please post a mockup of your output. I guess Tyler is right here.

Comment: `justify-content: center;` -> `justify-content: space-between;`. see [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self):

> `flex-start`

> The cross-start margin edge of the flex item is flushed with the cross-start edge of the line.

This means `align-self: flex-start;` will align the top edge of your `top` box with the top edge of the `flex` box (the beginning of the cross axis).

The left/right values are along the main axis. You can read more about it in the W3C spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#align-self-property

One way to accomplish your desired layout is to use `position` properties.

Note that the addition of `position` will change the flex behavior; it's sort of an "override" property. `align-self` on absolutely-positioned boxes applies along the containing block's block axis (in this case, the `y-axis`).

You can see more info about absolutely-positioned flex items here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#abspos-items

```css
.Aligner {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative; /* new */
}

.Aligner-item {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.Aligner-item--top {
  align-self: flex-start;
  left: 0; /* new */
  top: 0; /* new */
  position: absolute; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--top">…</div>
  <div class="Aligner-item">…</div>
  <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--bottom">…</div>
</div>
```